# CV: Translate GPA when applying for an international company

Tags: resume

I graduated from a German university and the German rating system ranges from 1.0 (best) to 4.0 (worst). This is exactly the opposite of the American system. When I want to apply for an international company for an international remote position, should I include my original final grade as mentioned on the graduation certificate or should I translate it into the American system?

My previous solution to this would be to write "1.2 (very good)", but I'm afraid that if the recipient won't read further than "1.2", associating this with a very bad grade.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the US GPA in parenthesis and provide a translation link somewhere.

For example

> 2019: M.Sc. Electrical Engineering, TH Darmstadt, Germany, German Grade: 1.2 (US GPA: 3.8)

For translation see https://welcometogermerica.com/2015/07/american-to-german-grade-conversion.html

While many international companies can translate this themselves, I wouldn't rely on it, especially if you resume is scanned by a first line staffer (who tend to be new and inexperienced).

Comment: And I find those who “self-translate” can be **too** generous. But they never make the error the other way ie making themselves look worse, funny that…

Comment: Hence you should cite the translation source. That gives you some credibility.

Comment: Can't be bothered, prefer to deal with the students needing help. Gave my opinion of how it works and if it is not valued then fine.

Comment: How will that help in countries that use neither system?

Comment: @gidds: You translate to the system you believe the HR department will be familiar with.

Answer (score -2):

International companies deal with records from international applicants and have their own correlation mechanisms in place.

Record your results correctly, including the contact details of each awarding institution so HR can contact if they need to.

Provide copies of all transcripts and be prepared to show the originals at interview.

I work in an establishment with students from 90 countries so dealing with variations between systems is normal.